# How can i Import a report generated with iReport to Jasper Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

I have some reports that were made and generated with iReport, but now i want to use Jasper Studio to make new ones, how do i import import it to jasper studio?

Comment: No need to do some additional steps. You can easy open template with Studio (menu File -> "Open File")

Comment: iReport working with .jrxml files, and after build it creates .jasper file. Jasper Studio works with .jasper files, but it can open both types. If it opens .jrxml file it automaticly convert this file to .jasper file.